# How to pause/continue a FluidSim without Stopping the Simulation?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

Basically, I'm doing a fluid simulation that needs to stop at one frame and continue 50 frames later. I'm doing this by keyframing the "Enable" toggle on the Inflow object ON and OFF.

However, every time I make it stop, the Domain shows up in view as a cube(which is what the Domain is) and then goes back to being a fluid 50 frames later when I enable it, getting rid of the fluid that was generated previously. Isn't there a way, for the existing fluid that has been simulated to stay on the scene, until it reaches the frame the enables it to generate more fluid again?

Answer (score 1):

This is hilariously late, but you can hover the mouse over the render button in the outliner (looks like a camera) and keyframe this to be off whenever the the unwanted domain box appears. Hope this could help someone with the same problem at least.